# If a char is an empty space, replace it with a '+' in C++

Tags: c++, char

I can't tell what's wrong with my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string test;
    cin>>test;
    if (test[4] == ' ')
    {
        test[4] = '+';
    }
    cout<<test<<endl;
    system("PAUSE"); 
    return 0;
}
```

I'm basically asking the user to give me a string (the string will be "star trek") and then, I want the string to be replace with a '+'. For some reason, I'm getting this whenever I try it. However, when I run this, I get a dialog box that pops up and says "Debug Assertion Failed" and "Expression: String subscript out of range".

Comment: You should be testing the length of the string before accessing a specific character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getline(cin,test)` as it won't skip whitespace. Also, please use cin.get() instead of `System("Pause")`.

Something like this would be better.

```
for(int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
    if(test[i] == ' ')
        test[i] = '+';
}
```

Comment: You are so awesome! Thank a lot for your help. I seriously appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

I'd generally avoid writing the loop yourself and use an algorithm instead when you can:

```
std::getline(std::cin, test);

std::replace(test.begin(), test.end(), ' ', '+');
```

Answer (score 1):

`<<` will read a string, stopping at whitespace, so it's cutting off your example string at the first space. In your example, `test` will only contain `"star"`, not `"star trek"`. Hence index *4* is invalid.

Use `getline` to read the entire input line.

You should also check your input length:

```
getline(cin, test);

if (test.length() > 4)
    test[4] = '+';
```