# How to replace one char by another using std::string in C++?

Tags: c++

How to replace one char by another using `std::string` in C++? In my case, I'm trying to replace each `c` character by  character.

I've tried this way :

```
std::string str = "abcccccd";
str = str.replace('c', ' ');
```

But, this wouldn't work.

Comment: A few seconds of searching [came up with this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12152291/1322972).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find and replace all characters in a string with specific symbols C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546367/how-to-find-and-replace-all-characters-in-a-string-with-specific-symbols-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a character in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896600/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-character-in-string)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the [`std::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) algorithm:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string str = "abccccd";
  std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), 'c', ' ');
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```